# Can I prevent JTidy from converting an apostrophe in an attribute value to an entity

Tags: jtidy

My input HTML has a line similar to this:

```
<div class="image" style="background:url('/images/someImage.jpg') no-repeat;"/>
```

which JTidy is converting to

```
<div class="image" style="background:url(&apos;/images/someImage.jpg&apos;) no-repeat;"/>
```

Is there a way to suppress that entity conversion? There appears to be a config method for preventing double quotes from being converted (setQuoteMarks()), but I don't see similar for apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the escapeXml() method?

If so try the escapeHtml3() or escapeHtml4() method.